# How to `read` and echo whatever the user typed?

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm making this script: when you type

```
"my name is [your name]"
```

it tells you

```
"hi, [your name]".
```

However, I don't know how to make `[your name]` anything you type. I've made a script with a particular name, but I want it to echo whatever name the user enters:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Say something: " sth
  if [[ $sth = "my name is ralph" ]]
      then
          echo "Hi $(echo $sth | cut -f 4 -d ' ')"
  else
      echo "I didn't understand that"
  fi
```

So this will echo `Hi ralph`, but how to make it echo `Hi [your name]` with whatever name you typed?

Comment: `if [[ $sth = "my name is ralph" ]]`, but you ask to `echo "Hi <NAME>"`... If it will only work for the name Ralph, do `echo Ralph`, otherwise, change your script/question to show your intentions.

Answer (score 3):

The specifics aren't given by you but generally you capture *name* like this.

```
#!/bin/bash   

regex='[Mm]y(\ name\ is\ )(\w*)'

read -p "Say something: " response

echo $response

if [[ "$response" =~ $regex ]]; then

        name=$(echo $response | cut -d' ' -f4)

        echo "Hi $name"
else
        echo "I didn't understand that"

fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the regex test `=~` to capture whatever comes after `my name is`:

```
$ read -rp "Say something: "; if [[ "$REPLY" =~ [Mm]y\ name\ is\ .* ]]; then echo "Hi "${REPLY:11}"" ; fi
Say something: my name is zanna
Hi zanna
```

Here I used a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the first 11 characters (`my name is`) and print whatever came after it, but if the user typed more than their name, the result might be not what you want:

```
Say something: my name is pixie and I eat flowers
Hi pixie and I eat flowers
```

[George's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/894092/527764) deals with this using `cut` to print only the 4th field (but I guess the user might type `My name is Super Rainbow Unicorn` and you might not want the shell to reply only `Hi Super`).

more readably and with an `else`:

```
read -rp "Say something: "
if [[ "$REPLY" =~ [Mm]y\ name\ is\ .* ]]
  then 
    echo "Hi "${REPLY:11}""
  else
    echo "I didn't understand that."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Zanna and George both did the right thing in using regexes, but then stopped short of actually using Bash's regex support to extract the name. With something like:

```
regex='[Mm]y(\ name\ is\ )(\w*)'
read -p "Say something: " response

if [[ "$response" =~ $regex ]]; then
```

After the `[[ ]]` regex test is done, bash makes available  the regex groups matched in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. For example (with input `My name is foo bar baz`):

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
My name is foo
 name is 
foo
```

So, modifying the groups a bit:

```
$ regex='My name is (\w.*)'
$ [[ "$response" =~ $regex ]]
$ printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
My name is foo bar baz
foo bar baz
```

Better still, you can tell bash to use case-insensitive regex matching:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
```

Combining all of this:

```
regex='My name is (\w.*)'
read -rp "Say something: "
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $REPLY =~ $regex ]]
then 
    echo "Hi ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
    echo "I didn't understand that."
fi
```

(Also, this lends itself quite easily to extracting the first word of a name, or the last.)

Answer (score 2):

### Two lines of code: `printf` for the prompt, `sed` for everything else.

You might consider not using `read` at all. There are many standard utilities that may be used by themselves or in scripts. One utility that works for this is [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sed.1.html), the [*stream editor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).

```bash
printf 'Say something: '
sed -r 's/^[Mm]y name is (.+)/hi, \1/; tQ; s/.*/I didn\x27t understand that/; :Q; q'
```

That's it. That's all you need.

### How It Works

`printf` prints the prompt. No newline is appended.

`sed` processes input line-by-line. When not supplied a filename, it reads from [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29), as does the `read` command. In this case we are stopping after just the first line (like the read command does), which is what [the `q` at the end](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-q-_0028quit_0029-command) is for--it quits. In general, `sed` is used to process multiple lines of input, often every line in a file, but here we only want one line.

Both Bash and Sed are languages and they both have a notion of *commands*. Each line above is a single Bash command, but within the single-quoted Sed script passed to `sed`, there are multiple Sed commands.

**The first Sed command** is `s/[Mm]y name is (.+)/hi, \1/`. It [performs substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) (`s/`). It searches:

- `^` - at [the very beginning](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) of the line
- `[Mm]` - for [`M` or `m`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `y name is`  - for that literal text, including the trailing space
- `(.+)` - for [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (`+`) of [any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (`.`). This is what we are taking to be the user's name. Because it is enclosed in parentheses, and this is the first occurrence of `(` in the pattern, it is captured into the first group and accessible via the first [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), `\1`.

It replaces such text with:

- `hi,`  - that literal text, including the trailing space
- `\1` - the text that matched `.+` in the search pattern

**The second Sed command** is `tQ`. You can also write that `t Q`. It [tests](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-t-_0028test-and-branch-if-successful_0029-command):

- if the match operation attempted by the preceding `s` command succeeded.
- If it did, it skips to the [*label*](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_003a-_0028label_0029-command) `:Q`, which appears later.

That achieves the goal of skipping over the next command unless the user didn't enter usable input. The function of the next command is to inform the user that their input wasn't understood, after all.

**The third Sed command** is `s/.*/I didn\x27t understand that/`. It searches for:

- `.*` - Zero or more characters. This always matches the entire line.

That provides a way to do nothing further with the input, and instead replace it all with the message we want to display:

- `I didn` - that literal text
- `\x27` - a `'` character, since we are using `'` in the shell to pass the whole script to `sed` (otherwise it would be fine to include a literal `'` in the Sed script)
- `t understand that` - that literal text

**The label** `:Q`. [Labels](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_003a-_0028label_0029-command) in Sed start with a `:` but when they are branched to with the Sed command `t` (see above) the `:` is omitted. You can call this what you like, just change all `t` commands that use it accordingly.

**The final Sed command**, `q`. This [quits](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-q-_0028quit_0029-command) `sed`. Since this Sed command is always encountered after processing a line, no more than one line is ever processed.

### Portability Considerations

The `sed` command shown above is actually not portable to all Sed implementations because it uses two features that are not standard, but are instead provided specifically by [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/), the Sed implementation in most GNU/Linux systems including Ubuntu.

1. The escape sequence `\x27` to mean `'` (and hexadecimal escapes in general).
2. Semicolons around labels. The `;` is generally just as good as a newline to split separate Sed commands, but some implementations don't allow it around labels.

If you actually want to fix these problems, so you can run the exact same command on other OSes like macOS and FreeBSD that don't have GNU Sed (unless you install it on them), then you can simply use:

```bash
sed -r 's/^[Mm]y name is (.+)/hi, \1/
tQ
s/.*/I didn'\''t understand that/
:Q
q'
```

This works because Bourne-style shells like Bash permit literal newlines to appear inside single quotes. [The sequence `'\''`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187654/11938) ends quoting, supplies a `'` that is itself *separately* quoted due to [the immediately preceding `\` character](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character), and then resumes single quoting. This does still presume you are using a Bourne-style shell, though not necessarily `bash`.

An alternative is to use the `$'` `'` syntax, which is not actually standardized, and not all Bourne-style shells support it, though several popular ones do. In this way you can still probably write it as a true one-liner while using only standard *Sed* features, though I urge you *not* to do it this way because it's more confusing:

```bash
sed -r $'s/^[Mm]y name is (.+)/hi, \\1/\ntQ\n s/.*/I didn\x27t understand that/\n:Q\nq'
```

Besides `\x27` being replaced with `'`, `\\` is replaced with `\` and `\n` is replaced with a newline, causing `sed` to receive the same Sed script as with the above multi-line command that you should use instead anyway.

***My thanks go out to [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna), who [suggested `t` might be used](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41222702#41222702) for this and [helped me simplify](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41223243#41223243) the Sed script once it was written.***

Answer (score 0):

Got this from other people's responses here, then did some modification of my own. This is just for a single, simple thing you can easily make into a command. There's no interpretation of the format, it won't protect against invalid entry, etc.

```
read -p username: username ; curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$username/repos?per_page=100" | grep -o 'git@[^"]*'
```

Answer (score -1):

You are having a problem with your script because you are using the `=` operator which is making an assignment to your `$sth` variable rather than making a comparison between the two.

Use the the double equal symbol (`==`) in place of the single (`=`).  The `==` is an operator for pattern match.

**Change your conditional statement:**

**Change from:**

```bash
if [[ $sth = "my name is ralph" ]]
```

**Change to:**

```bash
if [[ $sth == "my name is ralph" ]]
```

Comment: But what if the name is not ralph? That isn't what they want to test...

Comment: I was hoping that I explained what the details of using the operator and assignment.  The structure the OP had appeared that he was trying to apply a condition statement.  My answer was an attempt to help the user to see how to use the operator.  He used a condition statement that would never change.  Because of that, I'm sure it was giving the user confusion... continued

Comment: ...   Looking at the sample code it appeared that he was thinking whatever he was typing was not being assigned to his variable.  If he corrected the condition statement he could notice that what the user typed was stored in his read variable **sth**.  If he tested it correctly, he would realize that his assignment is working.  The `read -p` is pitting what the user type into the variable **sth**.  He said, how to I read and echo what the user typed?  He had already read what the.. user typed.    Now he can test what the user typed and echo what the user typed in the code he posted...

Comment: @Zanna His question appeared clear to me.  I answered what it appeared what he was saying, and tried to explain in my answer the part that I was answering for him.  It appears from your answer that you are seeing something different in his question than what I was seeing.  But he typed clearly the input he wanted to go into his code.  If you test his code and put the input he said **when I type**: `"my name is [your name]"`.  His question might be interperted a little different to you.

Comment: Ok, but the varying part is the name itself, isn't it? How to echo the name whatever it is, not only if it is ralph?

Comment: His question appeared that the variable was not just the name.  The variable that he was to capture was a phrase: **`"my name is [your name]"`**.  I understand it's possible that I may have misunderstood his intentions, but from what he typed, it appears rather clear to me that he was trying to test a phrase not a single name.

Comment: Yeah, the whole phrase will be tested - the user has to enter "my name is..." but the name will change, hence the contrast between ralph and [your name] - I think that is the point (see my answer?)

Comment: This answer is wrong. `=` in `[[` or `[`/`test` does *not* perform assignment. [**Try it!**](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25986271/)